# RuntimeWarning while using lambda function (Win8 computer)

Tags: windows, pythonxy

I installed Python(x,y)-2.7.5.0 to run python programs on my Win8 Laptop. The Programs run on Linux, but when I use python(x,y) I get this error message:

> D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:402: RuntimeWarning: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 2800.
>   warnings.warn(errors[info][0], RuntimeWarning)

The error occurs during a harmonic analysis at the "func= lambda..." part:

```
y = N.ravel(zon[:,z,k,:])
print k                 
func = lambda p,s,c,y: fitfunc(p,s,c) - y # Distance to the target function
print k                   
p1, success = optimize.leastsq(func, p0[:], args=(s,c,y))
```

I looked it up, where maxfev is defined, but I guess, it´s not a good idea to change it. My question is, whether the error is caused by a bug of python(x,y) or by my Windows 8 system. How can I search after the answer?

Does anybody else use Python(x,y)-2.7.5.0 with a win8 computer?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Padraic Cunningham ([python 64 package for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158108/python-64-package-for-windows)), I installed Anaconda 64bit for windows. There are no problems anymore. Thus I think, one problem might have been the 32bit Version of pythonxy. Another aspect might be, that I didn´t use the latest version of pythonxy, but I´m not sure about that.